# how #Include works when I compile a linux kernel

Tags: c, linux

I need to compile a 2.6.28 linux kernel with arm-linux-gcc as an embeded system.I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 x86.
I viewed the 2.6 kernel source code and found this:

```
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <asm/io.h>
#include <asm/irq.h>
...
```

Will gcc compiler include these files from /usr/include    /usr/local/include **or** from Linux_2.6.28 source folder?

Comment: Let me check gccs manual for you, just a moment...

Comment: Obviously not ! Take a look at the main Makefile, you will find it in the root of your kernel source tree. Then just search for "include". This should give you the answer you are looking for ;)

Comment: The kernel will not look into your local file as already answer. BUT, if you compile user-space applications to run in your embedded system, you must change your PATH and/or manually pass your kernel source dir to the make command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Kernel is *self-contained*. This means that it is not allowed to have any external dependency. In other words, your Kernel source tree contains *all* the material needed to build your Kernel. There is no point to look for code anywhere else.

As I suggested in my comments, just take a glance at the main Makefile. You'll find it under the root of your source tree. A little `ctrl+f` with "include" and here's interesting quotes I can feed back to you :

```
# Look for make include files relative to root of kernel src
MAKEFLAGS += --include-dir=$(srctree)
# .... Other stuff
# Use USERINCLUDE when you must reference the UAPI directories only.
USERINCLUDE    := \
    -I$(srctree)/arch/$(hdr-arch)/include/uapi \
    -Iarch/$(hdr-arch)/include/generated/uapi \
    -I$(srctree)/include/uapi \
    -Iinclude/generated/uapi \
    -include $(srctree)/include/linux/kconfig.h

# Use LINUXINCLUDE when you must reference the include/ directory.
# Needed to be compatible with the O= option
LINUXINCLUDE    := \
    -I$(srctree)/arch/$(hdr-arch)/include \
    -Iarch/$(hdr-arch)/include/generated \
    $(if $(KBUILD_SRC), -I$(srctree)/include) \
    -Iinclude \
    $(USERINCLUDE)
```

Answer (score 3):

These files should not be directly accessible in the /usr/local etc. If they are, it's a problem, because your kernel will not build correctly unless it uses the ones that belong to that kernel. Some of these files change on a regular basis, as the kernel is being updated and improved.

The files used by the kernel are found in the `linux/include/...` directory. The compiler options use `-nostdinc` to avoid the standard include locations from being searched, and then add the appropriate locations from within the kernel source directory.

Comment: Good information!  I've deleted my answer as I obviously missed that point.

Answer (score 2):

To find out what files are included for some given compilation, pass `-H` to `gcc`.

To add a directory for searching included files, pass `-I` *somedir*  to `gcc`, e.g. `-I /usr/local/include/`; there are [preprocessor options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) to remove directories or to clear the include path.